# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null. var one printing null

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, addeventlistener

```
console.log("connected");

var one = document.getElementById("Click")

console.log(one);

one.addEventListener('click',function a() {
    one.textContent = 'Clicked';
})
```

**Even Variable one is printed null in console**

The HTML code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en" dir="ltr"> 
    <head> 
        <meta charset="utf-8"> 
        <title></title> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <script src="x.js"></script> 
        <h1 id="Click">Click</h1> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please say, when you're actually including `<script>` tag?
And also, if it's possible, could you provide `html` code as well?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="x.js"></script>
    <h1 id="Click">Click</h1>
  </body>
</html>
My HTML code

Comment: You have your script running before you defined your h1, place the script before the `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Keith's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65167366/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-addeventlistener-of-null-var-one-pri/65167562#comment115209194_65167366) works. But a cleaner way is to only add the event listener if the DOM has loaded (i.e., assign your code to the `window.onload` function). That way, you can leave the `<script>`-Tag whereever you want (recommended is within `<head></head>`).
And remove the a from `function a()`, because you are passing the function in as an anonymous function and thus it should have no name. Like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    console.log("connected");

    var one = document.getElementById("Click");

    console.log(one);

    one.addEventListener('click', function() {
        one.textContent = 'Clicked';
    });
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

## The error

is telling you that the tag does not exist (yet).

## The reason

is that HTML evaluates from top-to-bottom, so your script is evaluated *before* your tag with that specific id is created.

## A simple solution

is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en" dir="ltr"> 
    <head> 
        <meta charset="utf-8"> 
        <title></title> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <h1 id="Click">Click</h1> 
        <script src="x.js"></script> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

This evaluates your tag first and then the script which assumes its existence. Even though this should work, it's assuming some rules in your HTML, which is not very elegant.

## An elegant solution

is the following:

```
function load() {
    console.log("connected");
    var one = document.getElementById("Click")

    console.log(one);

    one.addEventListener('click',function a() {
        one.textContent = 'Clicked';
    })
}
```

and

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en" dir="ltr"> 
    <head> 
        <meta charset="utf-8"> 
        <title></title> 
        <script src="x.js"></script> 
    </head> 
    <body onload="load()"> 
        <h1 id="Click">Click</h1> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

because this does not hinder your autonomy in writing and maintaining your HTML. The idea is that a function is created, which is triggered when `body` is loaded. When `body` is loaded, you can be sure that your `h1` is also loaded.